# a car that can fit six people?

Tags: locatives

Do you find the use of 'fit' natural in the following?

John needs a car that can fit six people.

My question is more of a grammatical or lexical nature; can 'fit' take 
as its subject a noun phrase that refers to a space? It can have a 
particular number of people or items as its subject:

E.g. Six passengers can fit in this car.

Or it can have a sentient agent as the subject:

E.g. We can fit one more person in this car.

But can it take a space as its subject? 
Can we say 'the car can fit six passengers'?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Generally one says it can _seat_ six people.

Comment: "the car" does not refer to a space. It refers to a car. But the answer to your question is yes, a space can be the subject of "fit," as in "This space fits 12 people."

Comment: @Silenus Well, the inside of a car is a space. Maybe a technical term like 'locative' should be used here. Anyway, do you say 'the car can fit 6 passengers'?

Comment: Yep, that sentence is fine. But as pointed out above, it is more common to say "the car *seats* six passengers".

Comment: @Silenus  Can you find any dictionaries that indicate or suggest that the subject of 'fit' can be a location such as a car or room?

Comment: Provided it has six seats ;) If a pickup truck fits six people it might have two seats and a lot of space on the cargo area

Comment: Oxford defines "fit" as "[with object] Be of the right shape and size for". There is no domain restriction on what can occur as the subject (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fit). Plus, I'm a native speaker and *very* confident you can use it that way.

Comment: @Silenus: I'm a native speaker too, and I think you're on *very* shaky ground claiming that because *those jeans fit me* is okay, you can naturally extend the usage to *lift fits four, sofa fits three, car fits five.* The first two of those have no written instances at all in Google Books, and the last has just 3 (as opposed to 452 instances of *car **seats** five*, being the standard form). For OP's context, a more valid alternative would be *John needs a car that can fit six people **in**.* Or ***fit in** six people*.

Comment: @Apollyon: An item of clothing *fits a fat person* if it's *fit = apt = appropriate [in size]* for a fat person (by implication, it *doesn't* fit thin people). But when we say a space (car, room, etc.) can ***fit [in]*** six people, this doesn't have the same implications of "aptness" - it just means it's *possible* to cram that many people in (though if there were only four people in the car, they might be far more comfortable, making four a more fitting/apt occupancy level).

Comment: 'That car is a six-seater'

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think the Oxford dictionary has an example that indicates that 'fit' can indeed take a space or location as the subject:                 'We have a large range of picture frames of all shapes and sizes to fit any photo, from a back yard snapshot to a professional portrait or even a personal artwork.' Here, the implied subject of 'fit' is 'a large of picture frames of all shapes and sizes'.

Comment: @Apollyon: We're coming at this from different angles. As a competent native speaker I don't really need to consult dictionaries to find out what's "normal" for straightforward idiomatic usages such as this one. But since I *do* usually already know, I'm well equipped to know what specific sequences I'm likely to find in Google Books to illustrate my point. You should also note the significance of ***can*** in your example (in isolation, implying "at a pinch", although this can be overridden in "ad-speak" by saying *can **comfortably** seat/fit/hold six*).

Comment: Perhaps more so than ... “can **seat** six people” and .... “can **hold** six people,” I think ... “can [**accommodate**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/accommodate) six people” ... provides some clues to this/your [“Transitive sense {of *fix*, from 1590s} of ‘provide with what is suitable’”](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fit): …  “John needs a car that can provide six people with suitable space.”

Comment: Agree with @V0ight. See seven-seater reviews at http://www.which.co.uk/reviews/cars/article/best-cars/best-seven-seater-cars though perhaps OP really wants word "fit". BTW one would rarely say 5-seater as it's the implicit default in Europe at least.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of ***[fit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fit)*** is

> [*WITH OBJECT*]
>
> Be of the right shape and size for.
>
> '*Those jeans still fit me.*'

Notice that there is no domain restriction on what can appear as a subject. This suggests that the verb *fit* can take words that denote locations, spaces, and containers as subjects.

In fact, here are some examples from the *[Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)* (unfortunately, I can't link to the specific texts where these occur):

> 1. a two-sided beach cabana that **fits** one adult and two children
> 2. with a roomy and useful rear seat that easily **fits** two
> 3. My tub **fits** two people
> 4. a good small or medium-sized grill that **fits** 15 or more burgers on its cooking surface
> 5. Best of all, this visceral ride has four doors and **fits** four full-size adults
> 6. the hovercraft **fits** four people and two bags, and zips around at up to 65 mph.
> 7. The two-door all-wheel-drive vehicle **fits** four adults
> 8. Fiat's trunk **fits** five suitcases
> 9. Despite its name, the Mazda5 actually **fits** six passengers in three rows of seats
> 10. it **can fit** four pairs of skis or two base-to-base snowboards
> 11. The straight trucks, which are already at the loading docks, **can fit** eight pallets each
> 12. Rooms that **can fit** 80 people that have 100 people in them are often way more intense
> 13. it stages about one visual arts show a year, in a space that **can fit** 1,800 people

Notice that many of these are specifically about cars (or hovercrafts).

These examples should encourage you that your sentence "The car can fit six passengers" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps the most exhaustive answer. Great!